# How to select the most recent observation based on certain criteria on the previous observed date

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-query

community,

I have a problem in creating a table that gives the latest reported observation for a loan. I created a sample code to run.

```
declare @table1 table
(
 reference_date int
, Loan_id varchar(20)
, maturity int
, status_loan int
, repayment_date int

)

insert @table1 values
(2009, '001_AA', 2030, 1, NULL)
, (2010, '001_AA', 2030, 1, NULL)
, (2011, '001_AA', 2018, 4, 2018)
, (2012, '001_AA', 2018, 4, 2018)


select t3.*
FROM @table1 t3
WHERE t3.reference_date>='2008' and t3.reference_date<='2019'
and t3.reference_date = (SELECT MAX(t4.reference_date)
             FROM @table1 t4    
             WHERE t4.Loan_id = t3.Loan_id)
```

In the dataset reference_date is the report date, loan_id is the name of the loan, maturity is the loan end date, status is 1 for performing, 4 for repaid, repayment date is the date when the loan has been repaid.

As you can see in the database when a loan is repaid (status_loan=4) the maturity change to the date when the loan has been repaid.

What I want to have is the actual and original maturity date, see if that maturity date is before '2019' and only in this case, download the observation.

Any Idea?

Comment: i think order by clause will solve your problem. give it a try

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I do not think that order by could be the solution but I will try.

Comment: No idea.  What result set do you want?